# PWA using Vuejs with webpack: how to minify service worker code?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, progressive-web-apps

I am coding a PWA based on Vuejs and using webpack as a bundler. I am also using:

- Terser to minify/mangle the source code
- Google Workbox to help with the service worker
- Some other webpack plugins to copy code that my service worker will need, and clean it from `import/export` statements that service worker dont support

Now I would like to minify and mangle the code used by the service worker as, to my surprise, it is not done by default. Any clue on how to proceed? I can't find anywhere where to apply Terser to the service worker code and am still very new to webpack...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing my own Webpack plugin. This plugin will:

0. Activate before any other plugin
1. Gather Vue environment variables (`provcess.env.VUE_APP_*`)
2. Merge together all the files + environment variables needed by the service worker (instead of using `ImportScripts`). Mangling the files separately wont work, hence this step.
3. Run Terser on the merged file.
4. Copy the result to the public folder so it picked up by Webpack normal build process.

I will push the code here once it is cleaned-up....